# Symfony2 merging Bundle configurations

Tags: symfony, configuration

I'm working on a Symfony2 application that can be enhanced via additional Bundles. My idea is that all the configuration work is done in the bundles itself. My problem is now: How do I add additional entries to an existing configuration? Lets take the security.yml file of Symfony2 for example. There is an entry for access control. In my application/config/security.yml there is something like this:

```
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: /.*, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

In my Bundle i want to add more access_controll paths. So what I want is to create a security.yml file there too and define the access_control settings of the Bundle there. If I do so I overwrite the existing settings.

Comment: What about just including the files of a bundle? I personally don't think that merging over overwriting the config file would be a better option, because you never knows what a 3rd party bundle will do to your application.

Comment: Did you found a solution for this? rather then just including?